# Verify code is running on user-interface thread in Vaadin 7 app

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Is there some way to verify that code is executing on the user’s user interface thread (event loop thread)?

This question is the Vaadin equivalent of this question, [Swing verify code on Event Dispatch Thread at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3014972/642706).

I know how to call [`UI::access`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#access(java.lang.Runnable)) from a background thread to schedule a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) to be run on the user-interface thread. My question is how to double-check that some executing code is indeed running on the user-interface thread.

I filed a [feature request](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/16526) for this.

Comment: You mean server side thread? Some logging can help, for example slf4j

Answer (score 1):

## UI.getCurrent()

If [`UI.getCurrent()`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#getCurrent()) returns an instance you are (most probably) either:

- On a thread started by UI interaction
- On a thread that is already initiated with [`UI::access`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#access(java.lang.Runnable))

To quote the Vaadin 7.3.9 doc:

> … In other cases, (e.g. from background threads), the current UI is not automatically defined.

### Example Code

```
boolean uiOrUiAccessManagedThread = UI.getCurrent() != null;
```

Comment: Thread started by UI interaction does not by itself synchronize anything. You'd also want to check ui.getSession().hasLock().

Answer (score 1):

The framework is already full of asserts in various code paths that should only be run on the thread that has locked the UI state. The most important being whenever shared state is accessed.

To benefit from this checking, just make sure your server is run with assertion checking enabled, i.e. by starting it with the `-ea` JVM parameter.